# Get the Icon name as string in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I wanna get the name of an icon in flutter
fot example:

```
Icon(CryptoFontIcons.NOTE)
```

i want to get "NOTE"
but I couldnt find any method for that
i want something like

icon.name

Comment: I'm afraid there is no name like that available. Could you explain why you need a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or try this u have to map the icons

```
_showIconGrid() {
    var ls = [
      Icons.extension,
      Icons.face,
      Icons.fastfood,
      Icons.favorite,
      Icons.favorite_border,
      Icons.home,
    ];

    var iconMap = Map<IconData, String>.fromIterable(
      ls,
      value: (item) {
        if(item == Icons.extension) {
          return "Icons.extension";
        }
        if(item == Icons.face) {
          return "Icons.face";
        }
        ...
        else {
          return "Unknown";
        }
      }
    );

    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 8,
      children: List.generate(ls.length, (index) {
        var iconData = ls[index];
        return IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print(iconMap[iconData]);    
            },
            icon: Icon(
              iconData,
            ));
      }),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).